# AJAX giving success but no changes made in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a function to change the user's email, this call will be made via AJAX on a button click. The form code is below, which is in a file named `profile.php`:

```
<form id="changeEmail" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="changeEmail">Update Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo $currentEmail; ?>">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="updateEmail" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
```

I have also created a `script` in this file as well to perform some basic functionality such as call the ajax function and hide the button until changed. See it below:

```
<script>
     $("#updateEmail").hide();
     var id = "<?php echo $id ?>";

     $("#email").change(function(){
        $("#updateEmail").slideDown();
     });

     var email = $("#email").val();

     console.log("id: " + id);
     updateEmail("<?php echo $id; ?>", email);
</script>
```

The AJAX function which I created is saved in a file named `profileAjax.js`, this file will hold all my profile ajax functions passing through the users id and new email address.

```
function updateEmail(id, email) {
$("#updateEmail").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent HREF

    $("#spinner").show(); // Show spinner

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({ // Perform Ajax function
            url: "../ajax/admin/updateEmail.php",
            dataType: "HTML",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: id, email: email},
            success: function (result) {
                $("#spinner").hide();
                $(".dashContent").html(result);
                console.log("This worked");
            }
        });
    }, 1500); // Delay this for 1.5secs
}); 
}
```

The final file which is called by the AJAX function is `updateEmail.php` which can be seen below:

```
include '../../functions/linkAll.inc.php';

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id");
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
updateEmail($id, $email);
```

The function which is called `updateEmail` is saved in an external file and works fully on its own.

```
function updateEmail($id, $email) {
$connect = db();

$stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE `Account` SET `email` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $email, $id);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    successMessage("Successfully updated your email address.");
} else {
    errorMessage($stmt->error());
}

$stmt->close();
}
```

However, when the update button is shown and clicked upon, it runs and gives a success message with nothing being updated in the database table itself.

Comment: You are not checking if a row was updated or not, you are only checking if the sql executed successfully. And no rows updated or found is not an error.

Comment: check [$stmt->rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) maybe your where condition does not match any accounts.

Comment: You have a js error: _ReferenceError: updateEmail is not defined_ in profile.php. It means that the updateEmail button is not yet defined. Surround the script content in profile.php with `$(document).ready(function () {...}`.

Comment: You don't need a submit button! Either a "button" + ajax, or only a "submit" without ajax..

Comment: Your _email_ argument passed to _updateEmail(id, email)_ is always an empty string. Read the email value inside `$("#updateEmail").click(...)` directly, not by passing it to the updateEmail() function as argument.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery AJAX success function is called when the requested source returns HTTP status 200. You should return something from PHP to the AJAX call to tell it if the database action was successfull.

Example PHP (called by AJAX request):

```
if($stmt->execute()) {
  echo "1";
}
else {
  echo "0";
}
```

Example JavaScript:

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data == "1") {
    //code if database action is successfull
  }
  else {
    //code if database action failed
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented this into the function now. I am logging out an error, as it is not continuing on with the update function. When the PHP updateEmail function is called on its own, it runs perfectly and executes, however just now through the AJAX request, why would this be?

Comment: The result I am getting back is a 1, which would be a successful update in this case; however, it still goes to the else part of statement

Comment: Have you checked if all POST data is passed with the AJAX request? You can check this with Developer Tools F12 -> Network -> XHR -> requested_file.php -> Scroll down to form data.